# CreateFile2 returns access denied error in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, visual-studio-2012

I have written the following lines of code to open a file under InstalledFolder directory:

```
Platform::String^ locationPath = Platform::String::Concat(Package::Current->InstalledLocation->Path, "\\Assets\\Logo.png");

CREATEFILE2_EXTENDED_PARAMETERS extendedParams = {0};
extendedParams.dwSize = sizeof(CREATEFILE2_EXTENDED_PARAMETERS);
extendedParams.dwFileAttributes = FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL;
extendedParams.dwFileFlags = FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN;
extendedParams.dwSecurityQosFlags = SECURITY_ANONYMOUS;
extendedParams.lpSecurityAttributes = nullptr;
extendedParams.hTemplateFile = nullptr;

Wrappers::FileHandle file(
    CreateFile2(
        locationPath->Data(),
        GENERIC_READ,
        0,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        &extendedParams
        )
    );

DWORD e = GetLastError();
if (file.Get() == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    throw ref new Platform::FailureException();
}
```

The CreateFile2 returns access denied error. Can anyone please help me out?

As suggested by JP Alioto, I have tried with WinRT File I/O as the following

```
    create_task(StorageFile::GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(ref new Windows::Foundation::Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Logo.png")))
    .then([=](StorageFile^ f)
    {
        auto p = create_task(f->OpenAsync(FileAccessMode::Read));
        p.wait();
    });
```

I still get the following error at p.wait():

> An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal

Thanks,

Comment: WinRT apps run in a sandbox with heavily restricted access to the file system.  Nothing you can do about it.

Comment: But I should be able to read a file under the deployment folder. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are passing `0` for `dwShareMode`.  The documentation for [`CreateFile2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh449422%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says that this value...

> Prevents other processes from opening a file or device if they request delete, read, or write access. Exclusive access to a file or directory is only granted if the application has write access to the file.

You do not have write access to files within the package, which is why you get the access denied error.  You need to set the share mode to `FILE_SHARE_READ`.

Comment: That's it. I wrote the code in Windows 8 RC and it worked there. Now in RTM it wasn't not working. With FILE_SHARE_MODE it's working perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: I no longer have the RC installed, but if I had to guess, I'd guess that the deployment that occurs prior to debugging was not setting the package root privileges correctly, and that this might have failed when _really_ deployed (e.g. via the store).  That's a wild guess, though.